# sequelize assocations ,how fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables user and guest, I want userId foreign key in guest table but when I create new guest, I have an error. How can I fix this?

```
 class Guests extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
       this.belongsTo(models.Users, { foreignKey: 'userId' });

      // // guestoperationsuser
      // this.hasMany(models.GuestOperationsUser);
    }
  }
  Guests.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: false,
      },
```

Comment: Please show the error message along with stacktrace in the post